# Calculate variance of random walk?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

How can I symbolically calculate the variance of the following random walk in *Mathematica*?

Given several discrete random variables such that $p(Z_i=1-2k)=p$, where $k$ is a small real number, and $p(Z_i=-1)=1-p$, a random walk is the sum $X_t = \sum\limits_{i=1}^t Z_i$.

The expectation is given by:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^t\mathbb{E}[Z_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^tp(1-2k) -(1-p) = (p(1-2k)+p-1)t$$

I would like to calculate the variance of the random walk $Var[X_t]$.

I tried using `EmpiricalDistribution`, but it does not accept symbolic values.

**EDIT**

After a bit more research into Mathematica's documentation I found the function TranformedDistribution.  Since my random walk does not have unit steps I thought maybe the distribution can be obtained from a Bernoulli like this:

```
TransformedDistribution[
 If[\[FormalX] == 1, 1 - 2 k, -1], \[FormalX] \[Distributed] 
  BernoulliDistribution[p]]
```

Could someone please show me how to use this to calculate $Var[X_t]$?  As someone in the comments said, the variance of $X_t$ is the sum of variances of $Z_i$ so at some point I will have to calculate $E[Zi^2]$ where $Z_i$ is a tranformed Bernoulli distribution like I attempted above?

Comment: Have a look at [`RandomWalkProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomWalkProcess.html).

Comment: This isn't really a question about *Mathematica*; it's a math-stat question. The answer is that the variance of $X_t$ is the sum of the variances of the $Z_i$ and the variance of $Z_i$ equals $p(1-p)(2-2k)^2$.

Comment: Thanks it would be instructive to see how you calculated variance of $Z_i$ because I don't know how to calculate $E[Z_i^2]$.  I posted here because I also would like to see how you can use Mathematica to calculate this.

Comment: @whuber poor original poster: --> Started off at math.SE, ... ignored there perhaps because of the Mma reference ... comes here ... and is shunted back there :)

Comment: What is the pleasure you get from mocking the other's ignorance?

Comment: Actually I think there is more sympathy than mockery.  A legitimate question, not thought appropriate for here, but without a good answer (yet) at math.SE.  Maybe stats.SE?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm curious, since I don't see it immediately — _why_ is this off-topic? It seems to be clearly about _Mathematica_, or rather, trying to derive the variance symbolically using _Mathematica_...

Comment: @rm-rf I was referring to the opinion of those who voted to close.  My probability is fairly rudimentary, and I'm afraid I don't understand the question very well.  I think if the question is, how do I set up this computation with Mathematica functions, then it is on topic.  That does seem what the OP is asking.

Comment: @dabd I feel this was closed because it wasn't immediately obvious that you're asking how to do it in _Mathematica_ (I know you mentioned it, but it was in the very last line). People might have thought you accidentally posted a question meant for [math.se] here. I've reopened it and rephrased your question slightly to indicate the _Mathematica_ part of it upfront. As to your question, Silvia's suggestion is a good start — if your steps were unit sized, then the variance can be found as `Variance@RandomWalkProcess[p][t]`, but since you have different step sizes, it needs a little more finesse

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for reopening the question. I edited the original question with what I have found in attempting to use Mathematica to solve this.

Comment: Essentially all the work needed to solve this takes place in order to write it down in *Mathematica.* $Z_i$ has a Bernoulli distribution that is shifted in mean and rescaled. Its variance will therefore be the variance of a Bernoulli distribution multiplied by the square of the scale factor. One way to obtain the scale factor is by looking at the relative range: $(1-2k-(-1))/(1-0)=2-2k$. If you don't know the variance of a Bernoulli distribution you would then type `Variance[BernoulliDistribution[p]](1-2 k-(-1))^2`. $X_t$, being the sum of $t$ of these, will have $t$ times the variance.